# generating .orm.yml file from a sql query

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

What is the best way to create entities (with configuration files) from available tables?

imagine that I have a create table query like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable`.`task` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
  `due_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `attachment` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `project_id` INT NULL,
  `user_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_task_1_idx` (`project_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_task_2_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_task_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`)
    REFERENCES `mava`.`project` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_task_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `mava`.`user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

is there any way that I can generate task.orm.yml file from this query.
I'm using symfony and doctrine and I have a bunch of tables defined already. So I need to generate Entities from them.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here:

[How to Generate Entities from an Existing Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)

Hope it helps someone else